# How to catch the moment, when the UIViewController is pushed to the front because back button was pressed?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

Well, the question is in the tittle:

**How to catch the moment, when the UIViewController is pushed to the front because back button was pressed?**

I need it to reload data on the list when it's UIViewController is on the front again. The problem is I don't want to do that every time the view appears, for example when the view is first shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to set a flag on your first controller, when you push into another view set it to YES and on your `viewWillAppear:` check if you need to do some reloading.

The other option, assuming your second view will configure some things for the view A, is to create a delegate method that let's the view A know it needs reloading.

The third option is to use a custom back button (rounded, not with the back button shape), capture the event and do the popViewController manually after you do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

then you make a new method and call it before the push (pop) on front the view controller and this method help you to reload the list on itself class also :-) i hope you understand what i want to say then when you want to reload the data you simply call that function and list is reload .